# How to parse date from string in Golang to insert into Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, go

So I'm trying to parse a time from a string and then insert that time into Postgres.

I have this so far-

```
layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"
updatedAt, _ := time.Parse("2016-06-10")
fmt.Println(updatedAt)
```

but this outputs

`0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC`.

I'm also not sure how to then use this to query in postgres (what format should the time have)?

Comment: Your `layout` and your `value` do not match AND you are not passing `layout` as a parameter: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse

Comment: Do you happen to know which layout works for UTC? And how to then use the output to insert into Postgres? I've tried a few and none work.

Comment: [`time.Parse`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse) takes 2 arguments, you're not passing in the layout. And like Nicarus said, you're layout doesn't match, you only need `2006-01-02`

Comment: All layouts work for UTC. If you need to use another location, use ParseInLocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To parse time in your example you'll need correct layout passed to `time.Parse`:

```
layout := "2006-01-02"
updatedAt, _ := time.Parse(layout, "2016-06-10")
fmt.Println(updatedAt)
```

Outputs:

```
$ go run time.go
2016-06-10 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

To insert time you have after parsing it you'll just need to pass `time.Time` object to `db.Exec`. For example:

`db.Exec("INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (time_column) (($1));", time.Now())`

Comment: This solution is NOT working for me with the pq driver...

Comment: Not sure why this answer is marked as accepted... Where is the time formating here?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert a specific date and not time.Now() you can use date.Format("2006-01-02")

```
layout := "2016-02-02T15:04:05.000Z"
updatedAt, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, layout)

fmt.Println(updatedAt)
fmt.Println(updatedAt.Format("2006-01-02"))
fmt.Println(updatedAt.Format(time.RFC3339))
```

return :

```
2016-02-02 15:04:05 +0000 UTC 
2016-02-02 
2016-02-02T15:04:05Z
```