# Timestamp with Timezone in GoLang

Tags: database, postgresql, datetime, go, driver

I make a HTTP call and unmarshal a createdTimestamp field from the larger json object:

```
CreatedTimestamp string `json:"createdTimestamp"`
```

An Example of what I receive from the HTTP call for the *createdTimestamp* would be: `"2021-07-19T18:51:23"`.

It won't automatically convert it to a `time.Time` so the only type it would really accept is a string which was working until the type changed in Postgresql to `timestamp with timezone` < looks like this according to Postgresql db console >`(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffffff)`. where as before it was `without timezone`.
I am able to implement a custom unmarshal method for the `time.Time` object and even format it so I can output something like `2021-07-19 18:51:23.+00` but this won't be accepted by postgres.

The exact error I see when trying to insert this (via GoLang, postgres driver) is: `pq: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: ""` 
This error comes after I try to execute an insert using `db.Exec` -> `db` being of type `*sql.DB`.

I'm doing this in **Go** , any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Code to Unmarshal Json**

```
type CustomTime struct {
    time.Time
}

func (ct *CustomTime) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    timeToInsertIntoDb := strings.Trim(string(b), "\"")
    if timeToInsertIntoDb == "null" {
        ct.Time = time.Time{}
        return
    }

    timeToInsertIntoDb = timeToInsertIntoDb + "Z"
    ct.Time, err = time.Parse(time.RFC3339, timeToInsertIntoDb)
    return
}
```

With formatting, it depends on the output but I do receive the output of whatever the format is. So if I do, `CustomTime.Time.Format(2006-02-01 15:04:05.-07)`
I will get the output of `2021-07-19 18:51:23.+00`

Though at this point, i'm not even sure about the exact format needed for `Timestamp with Timezone`, there isn't too much documentation on this for the Golang Postgres driver.

If there is any more information needed, please ask. I'm trying my best to organize this question.

**Edit 1**

---

As suggested, I tried to append on a 'Z' to the timestamp given from the http call. After doing a parse with `time.RFC3339`, I am given a time of `2021-07-19T18:51:23Z` - this still failed (gave the same syntax error stated above). Tried it a few different ways with this parsing. With it formatted the way I stated above, and with it formatted with it's `.String()` method which would give `2021-07-20 18:51:23 +0000 UTC`. Both failed with `pq: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: ""`

*Code Changes during Unmarshal:*

```
func (ct *CustomTime) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    timeToInsertIntoDb := strings.Trim(string(b), "\"")
    if timeToInsertIntoDb == "null" {
        ct.Time = time.Time{}
        return
    }

    timeToInsertIntoDb = timeToInsertIntoDb + "Z"
    ct.Time, err = time.Parse(time.RFC3339, timeToInsertIntoDb)
    return
}
```

---

**Edit 2**

Another thing to mention would be that I am using the `"database/sql"` package with the `"github.com/lib/pq"` as the *Postgres driver for DB connection*.
Which is why the error is from `pq`. Just wanted to clarify cause I know others are using gorm. I can write to other tables, it's just this table having the timestamp with timezone Postgres Column I guess.

I am making the call with `db.Exec("INSERT INTO db (created_timestamp) VALUES ($1)", obj.createdTimestamp.Time`
I've tried passing it along as a string (it's what I did before when it was working) but now this is where i'm at since people say it's better to pass a *time.Time* variable.

Comment: It you are able to successfully convert to a `time.Time` then pass that in as a parameter (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38755914/11810946)). Note that the examples in your question are inconsistent - does `createdTimestamp` include a timezone or not?

Comment: @Brits, so a timezone isn't included. What I get in the HTTP call is listed above, but the data I get is in UTC (existing knowledge on my behalf) and I have been trying to get it to store within that timezone. I tried to pass in a `time.Time` but that wouldn't work either. Please see `Edit 1` -- it has a few more details in what I just tried with a different `time.Parse`.

Comment: the error you face is specifcally postgre related. I suggest you give us a reproducible source code including the sql queries and execution like Shailesh Suryawanshi user did in his post. That would really help people to get it right. you might want to share the http handler code too, we never know.

Comment: @thatdevop if you are able to successfully convert `CreatedTimestamp` into a `time.Time`  then the source of the time is irrelevant and your question should be something like 'How do I use a `time.Time` with a Postgres `insert`' (and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Comment: @Brits It technically does have a timestamp now since i'm adding the "Z" during the unmarshal and then parse it as `RFC3339`. It is of type `time.Time` and i've made sure of that by logging the type before running a `db.Exec`. It used to work and I actually don't think there were any changes to the DB. Not sure what's going on here.

Comment: @thatdevop your question indicates that you are converting the `time.Time` back to a `string` before passing it to the `db.Exec`; please edit your question to show the database call (ideally a full reproducible example so we have all relevant info and can duplicate the issue ourselves).

Comment: @Brits I can't really give a reproducible example but i'm converting a `string` I get from an HTTP call _to_ `time.Time`. During Unmarshal now, I do a `time.Parse(time.RFC3339, ...)` now. I've updated the Unmarshal code in the body

Answer (score 4):

If you check the timeFormat `ctlayout` provided matches closely with the timeformat standard [RFC3339](https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants)

```
const ctLayout = "2006-01-02T15:04:05"
const RFC3339  = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
```

From this [blogpost](https://medium.com/easyread/understanding-about-rfc-3339-for-datetime-formatting-in-software-engineering-940aa5d5f68a).

> In RFC 3339, we can also know the time-zone from the format. It
> displayed in the “Z” syntax. “Z” means UTC+0. “Z” stands for Zulu
> timezone which is the same with GMT or UTC
> (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9706777/4075313). So if we put Z on the
> DateTime, it’s mean its timezone is UTC+0.

If we change the incoming time and append `'Z'` at the end the time parser should be satisfied.

Here is a refactored code. You can find working code on [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HHHDHe7s-gT).

```golang
        timeToInsertInDB := "2006-01-02T15:04:05" + "Z"

        testTime, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, timeToInsertInDB)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err) 
        }
```

Note :- More detailed example of timezones

```
2019-10-12T07:20:50.52Z      (UTC+0)
2019-10-12T07:20:50.52+00:00 (UTC+0)
2019-10-12T14:20:50.52+07:00 (UTC+7)
2019-10-12T03:20:50.52-04:00 (UTC-4)
```

The postgres driver expects `time.Time`. If the parsing is succesfull, driver should be able to insert into the database as well as unmarshall the response in the Model structs. Have a look at this example on [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/I8U-K1AT-bH).

**edit 1**

As per the OP's edit, I changed the drivers used I tried this with `database/sql` package and `github.com/lib/pq` but could not reproduce the issue. The insert and select worked completely fine. [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HFGBXLZvH9N)

As mentioned by Brits, this is most likely cause is a logic error in your code (but cannot confirm this as you have not shared the code).

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried appending 'Z' during unmarshal and it allowed me to parse with `time.RFC3339` which is definitely a step forward. if I do a `.String()` on the time, I get something like `2021-07-19 18:51:23 +0000 UTC` - but when I try to insert into the table I still get the error of: `pq: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: ""` I'm not sure if `RFC3339` is the format pq is expecting. I can't find documentation on it either.

Comment: I also tried to pass through with a `.format(time.RFC3339)` which would mean i'm passing in `2021-07-19T18:51:23Z` but that gave me the syntax error as well stated above

Comment: @thatdevop I tried this locally and works fine for me playground https://play.golang.org/p/I8U-K1AT-bH . The postgres driver only expects `time.Time` format. Please check the select statement at the end.

Comment: This is weird then, I honestly think it should work but the conversion is definitely successful. I've tried passing in different forms of `createdTimestamp.Time` like also passing in `createdTimestamp.Time.Format(time.RFC3339)` and more. I just keep getting the generic invalid timestamp error.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is difficult to answer because it does not currently contain sufficient information to allow me to replicate the issue.

As mentioned in the comments you can, and should, pass a `time.Time` when inserting timestamps into the database. Doing this means that the library takes care of passing the timestamp to the server in an appropriate format (and your code is likely to continue working if you move to, for example, SQL Server).

If you are passing a `time.Time` then the source of that time becomes irrelevant. This means your question does not really need to mention the conversion from JSON at all - just make sure you double check that this conversion is successful and you are passing the `time.Time` to Postgres.

The code below demonstrates this (and completes successfully for me with Postgres 13.1) - this code converts from JSON using the technique suggested by Shailesh Suryawanshi:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "DSN goes here")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    // Create the table (would not normally do this here but this means the demo is self contained)
    _, err = db.Exec("create temporary table db(created_timestamp timestamp with time zone)")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    jsonTS := `2021-07-19T18:51:23`
    ts, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, jsonTS+"Z")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _, err = db.Exec("INSERT INTO db (created_timestamp) VALUES ($1)", ts)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Test retrieving the value
    rows, err := db.Query("select * from db")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        var t time.Time
        err = rows.Scan(&t)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(t)
    }

    fmt.Println("Complete")
}
```

I can replicate your issue by running `db.Exec("INSERT INTO db (created_timestamp) VALUES ($1)", "")`; the full error is:

```
panic: pq: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: ""
```

It may be possible that your issue is due to something in the Postgres configuration; running a modified version of the above code against your server will enable you to confirm if that is the case. However, based on the above, I believe the most likely cause is a logic error in your code (but cannot confirm this as you have not shared the code).

Note: the [`lib/pq` readme](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/master/README.md) states: "We recommend using pgx which is actively maintained."